# Solr - range filter isn't working properly

Tags: solr

I'm starting with solr, and stuck in a weird behavior. I have a multivalued field:

```
<field name="facet_age_filter" type="text" indexed="true" multiValued="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true"/>
```

This field contains values from 0 to 12, I'm building my query like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/select?indent=on&q=BA048*&fq=facet_age_filter:[0 TO 3]
```

The problem is, in my results I have results that didn't mach the filter query. ie: samples from 4 to 12

Any thoughts about it?

As I said, I'm starting with solr, pointing out if I'm doing something very stupid or if I can find the solution in the docs (I couldn't find anything in the wiki).

EDIT:
Thank you for your comments.

Changed the field to Integer:

```
<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="facet_age_filter" type="integer" indexed="true" multiValued="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Changed it to store results to show in query response.

It works right if I filter as said by nickdos. But I still getting results outside the range.

Sample query result for the same query:

```
  {
    "cod":"BA048555",
    "facet_age_filter":[1,8]},
  {
    "cod":"BA048444",
    "facet_age_filter":[4,12]},
```

Is this right? These values in brackets?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried changing the field type to `integer`? Also confirm the field is configured correctly by doing a normal search on it like: `q= facet_age_filter:4`.

Comment: The change of type to integer should sort out the issue.

Comment: Did you re-index after changing it to the integer type?

Comment: yes, stoped, started and re-index. In Solr admin, it shows this field as integer, so I believe the configuration worked.